# How can i update another select tag(sub) from an onchange event of select tag(main) in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

Here is my code wherein functional condition need to change on react way

```
handleChange(event) {
    if (value == 'fra'){
       city will append
       <option>Paris</option>
       <option>Marseille</option>
    }else{
       city will append
       <option>Quezon</option>
       <option>Caloocan</option>
    }
  }


Country :<select id="country" name="source" onChange={this.handleChange}>
           <option value="fra">France</option>
           <option value="phi">Philippines</option> 
         </select>
City :   <select id="city" name="status"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update state depend on the country selected, like this :

```
handleChange(value ) {
    if (value == 'fra'){
       this.setState({data: ['Paris','Marseille']});
    }else{
       this.setState({data: ['Quezon','Caloocan']});
    }
  }
```

then in city component

```
 <select>{props.data.map((x) => <option key={x}>{x}</option>)}</select>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
const citiesFromCountry = {
  'france': [
    {
      value: 'paris',
      displayName: 'Paris'
    },
    {
      value: 'marseille',
      displayName: 'Marseille'
    }
  ],
 'philippines': [
    {
      value: 'quezon',
      displayName : 'Quezon'
    },
    {
       value: 'caloocan',
       displayName: 'Caloocan'
    }
 ]
}

const App = () => {
  const [country, setCountry] = React.useState('France')
  const [city, setCity] = React.useState('paris')
  const [cities, setCities] = React.useState(citiesFromCountry['france'])

  const handleChangeCountry = (event) => {
    setCountry(event.target.value)
    setCities(citiesFromCountry[event.target.value])
    setCity(citiesFromCountry[event.target.value][0].value)
  }

  const handleChangeCity = (event) => {
    setCity(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <select onChange={handleChangeCountry} value={country}>
        <option value="france">France</option>
        <option value="philippines">Philippines</option>
      </select>
      <select onChange={handleChangeCity}>
        {cities.map(city => (
          <option value={city.value}>{city.displayName}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/exifers/pen/ZEYOeyg)

Comment: I tried this, but it is not working? Actually what happens is that after I change the country the cities that are changed are not shown, I still can see the default city from earlier....